# Push method gives value null

Tags: java, object, null

I'm trying to create a push method that will place any given element first and push the already existing elements further in the array.

First of all i created a method to increase the size of the array and push the already existing elements further.

```
private void newBiggerObj(){
    Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (i == 0){
            temp[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr = temp;
}
```

I am then using this method inside:

```
    public void push(Object element) {
    newBiggerObj();
    arr[0] = element;

}
```

Assigning the new element at the supposedly empty space at arr[0].

The following code in the main method:

```
        hej.push(3);
    System.out.println(hej.toString());
    hej.push(4);
    System.out.println(hej.toString());
    hej.push(7);
    System.out.println(hej.toString());
    hej.push(2);
    System.out.println(hej.toString());
```

Gives me the print out:

`3 , 
4 , 3 , 
7 , 4 , null , 
2 , 7 , null , null ,`

Is there something simple wrong with the loop given that the 2nd attempt gives the right print out?

Answer (score 1):

You are not copying the old array to the new array. You only copy the first element:

Change

```
private void newBiggerObj(){
    Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (i == 0){ 
            temp[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr = temp;
}
```

to

```
private void newBiggerObj(){
    Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){            
        temp[i+1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr = temp;
}
```

Comment: That condition was there from an earlier attempt. Removing it fixed it all. Thanks!